# Using Django framework on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I would like to use the current release of the Django framework i.e. v1.2.3 on Google App Engine.
The article at http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html, says its now obsolete.

Can someone please point me to the correct documentation to follow for getting Django running on google app engine?

Answer (score 4):

see http://allbuttonspressed.com for most complete and up to date Django on GAE information.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want the linked article (from the documentation you quote?): http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html ?

It sounds like django-nonrel is a modification of the django framework including backends for "nonrel" i.e. non relational databases, like app engine.

Answer (score 0):

I found django non-rel a bit too unwieldy and need more control over how I make db calls.

anyway, this is what you need to do to get the lasted django set up:

1. download [django-app-engine-helper](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/)
2. unzip it, modify the app.yaml and use this as *your-project-dir*
3. download the latest [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/) and open/uncompress it. then zip up the /django sub-directory and make sure it's named django.zip
4. dump your latest version django.zip into *your-project-dir* (in the django-app-engine-helper parent directory)

and your ready to go!!!